# Stored procedure/functions in SparkSql

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Any ways to achieve sql features like stored procedure or functions in sparksql? 
I'm aware about hpl sql and coprocessor in hbase. But want to know if anything similar like is available in spark or not.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider of use  [User Defined Function](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html) and inbuilt function

A quick example

```
val dataset = Seq((0, "hello"), (1, "world")).toDF("id", "text")  
val upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase    
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val upperUDF = udf(upper)

// Apply the UDF to change the source dataset
scala> dataset.withColumn("upper", upperUDF('text)).show
```

**Result**

```
| id| text|upper|

+---+-----+-----+

|  0|hello|HELLO|

|  1|world|WORLD|
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create SP/Functions in SparkSql. However best way is to create a temp table just like CTE and used those tables for further usage. Or you can create a UDF Function in Spark.